ModuleInitializeException on Azure Deployment: Missing Dependencies for Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate Version 1.25.3
I'm using PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate" Version="1.25.3"  in my project. The application runs successfully on my local machine. However, when deployed to any environment in Azure, I encounter a ModuleInitializeException error. This error message states that "Azure.Identity" cannot be loaded for the module C:\home\site\platform\app_data\modules\TestModule.Web.dll.


Upon investigation, I found that the following libraries are missing in the Azure environment, causing the issue:

Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll
Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll
Azure.Identity.dll

These libraries appear to be related to the Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate package. I have tried upgrading and downgrading the package version, but the issue persists. Any suggestions for resolving this error?


Testing with different versions of Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate and related dependencies may resolve the issue.

If possible, share your code?

Please provide error in text format.

Have checked the Previous Answer?

Delete all the available dll's in the deployed App service KUDU, redeploy teh app and check again.

The Error related to missing dependencies for Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate .
It is working locally, fails on azure because of missing libraries Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll, Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal.dll, and Azure.Identity.dll.
This is because of version conflict between the  Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate package and other packages in your project.
You are using Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate Version 1.25.3 , this version only supported in .netcore 3.1, .NETFramework 4.6.2, .NETFramework 4.7.2.
As per this document if you are using .NET Core version 3.1 or .NET Framework, the related packages for Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate are Azure.Identity version >= 1.3.0 and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets version >= 4.1.0.
If you're using .NET Core 6 or above, use the latest version of Microsoft.Identity.Web.Certificate version 3.3.1.
For the compatible versions of related packages, refer to this document.
Update the packages according to the .NET version, then delete the bin and obj folders, and clear all NuGet cache storage by following the steps below.
Go To Tools ->NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet for Solution -> setting symbol ->NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Clear All NuGet Storage -> Ok.


Before redeploying the app to Azure App Service, delete all files in the wwwroot folder using the Kudu console, and then proceed with the deployment.

